# Bootstrap separating rows responsively

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make bootstrap separate add a row responsively. Maybe it is better draw it :D.

So here is what i have:

[image: 1st:]

And here is what i want to end up with:[image: 2nd:]

My html i like this but i know it doesnt work since it separates the first and the 2nd row into 2 rows (1st row 2 columns and 2nd row 1 column with the size of 6). So how to make this work,since i just started learning bootstrap today :)

My html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would making all the columns child of a single `.row` work for you?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```

I don't think it would be easy/practical to make new rows like you want.
If you want the rows only for styling purposes you are better off using css and determine different styles when the layout changes

Comment: didn't know you could have more than 12 in a row. This will work thanks